# How to simulate video traffic on omnet++

Tags: networking, video, simulation, omnet++

I am new to Omnet++ and would like to simulate video traffic on omnet++.
Which library should I use for it?
I found [VideoInterface](http://www.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/doc_details/2128-videointerface), but not sure is this the best one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you mean by 'videoTraffic' if you need only to simulate a roughly constant bitrate, you are fine with the stock INET with the built in UDP applications that can generate the required traffic just fine.

Comment: Dear @Rudi, I mean live video streaming, like Video conferance

Answer (score 0):

The recent INET Framework there is a UDP Application called VideoStream. You can create the pair of nodes with UDP application modules in them. Then, you just need to assign to one of the nodes the VideoStreamCli application and in the other the VideoStreamSrv application with all the necessary values. If you can provide the topology you have maybe someone can help you more

Answer (score -1):

I used OMNET++ to simulate wireless sensor networks. Graphical simulation is good.

See the OMNET++ documentation to learn its NED (module) language. You can define your nodes, and build traffic easily.

As far as i know, theres no need for any external library (unless you want it more fancy).

hope it helps :)

Comment: And how NED language will help on video stream simulation? :)))